# how to use set and get methods in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, object, get, set

I'm kind of confuse on how to use get and set in vb

how would i access the get/set method within the class and when i instantiate the class somewhere else?

in java i would make a 2 methods call like get_item set_item and i can just use the the method name i made. to retrieve or set within the class/object or when i instantiate it somewhere else. but in vb there is a property method and 2 methods inside(set,get)? 
i'm confuse... on how exactly to access these...

so for example if make a property call thing and made a property mstrThing

```
    Property Thing() As String

    Get
        Return mstrThing
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mstrThing = value
    End Set

End Property
```

how would i access Thing's get and set methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use property name within the instance method,

```
Thing="Hello"
```

To access properties outside the class, you have to specify `public` access modifier.

```
Dim obj as New ClassName
obj.Thing="Hello"
```

When an assignment operator is used to assign a value, the `set` `accessor` will be invoked.

For more info visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3dtbky.aspx) link.